# Задержка в функции MainWindow

Tags: c++, qt

Есть функция

```
void MainWindow::closeEvent (QCloseEvent *event)
{
    Break = 1;
    //задержка на 500мс ->после неё виполнить QApplication::quit();
    QApplication::quit();
    event->accept();
 }
```

Нужно при задержке чтоб в потоке с main.cpp не было задержки.
Иными словами main.cpp должен знать что Break=1 и при этом должна быть задержка в функции,которая в mainwindow.

Comment: Мне просто интересно, main.cpp вы имеете в виду поток ? Я думаю ван нужны эвенты

Comment: ну если просто поставить задержку то соответственно  main.cpp не будет исполняться

Comment: насколько я помню, main и гуй разные патоки в qt. И если это так, вы написали ерунду.

Comment: Если выключить a.exec, тогда по-сути не будет работать qt и зачем оно тогда надо? Обходитесь без qt

Comment: Ну у меня форма написана на QT.

Comment: не будут работать сигналы и слоты без запуска a.exec(). То есть вся суть qt будет нивелирована и потерян смысл его использования

Comment: Ну уменя до a.exec() випольняються действия с кнопками

Answer (score 3):

При помощи сигналов и таймера:

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow {
    Q_OBJECT
signals:
    void doBreak(int value);
    void doExit();

protected:
    void closeEvent(QCloseEvent* event) {
        emit doBreak(1);
        // Через 500 секунд просигнализировать, что пора на выход
        QTimer::singleShot(500, this, &MainWindow::doExit);
        // или
        // QTimer::singleShot(500, this, SIGNAL(doExit()));

        // Обязательно вызов ignore, иначе окно закроется сразу
        event->ignore();
    }
}

int main(...) {
    QApplication app(...);

    MainWindow window;
    QObject::connect(&window, &MainWindow::doBreak, <получатель сигнала>)
    QObject::connect(&window, &MainWindow::doExit, &app, &QApplication::quit);

    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: А можно как-то сказать app.exec() сразу завершаться после запуска?
В этом и задача

Comment: Потому что у меня в SFML свой цикл

Comment: В вашем примере окно `MainWindow` закроется сразу. Может здесь не надо `event->accept()`? закрытие главного окна автоматически завершит всё приложение.

Comment: @maestro возможно вы правы, писал по опыту. Надо бы потестить, а негде :)

Comment: @maestro вы абсолютно правы, исправил